# Pointer to function with default arguments

Tags: c++, c++14

Lets assume that we have a function

```
int foo (std::string, size_t = 0) { return 42; }
```

and I would like to call this function using wrapper function

```
template <typename T>
auto boo (std::string s) {
    return (*T::value) (s);
}
```

So, `T` should contain a pointer to appropriate function, so I declare it like this

```
struct Foo : std::integral_constant<int (*) (std::string, size_t), &foo> {};
```

and now the usage looks like this

```
std::cout << boo<Foo> ("b") << "\n"; // 42
```

On GCC 5.3.1 this code compiles fine but on GCC 6.3.1 and GCC 7.2.1 this fails to compile with an error

```
error: too few arguments to function
```

As far as I am concerned if I use a pointer to a function without wrapper template function

```
using Ptr = int (*) (std::string, size_t);
Ptr p = &foo;
auto x = p ("10");
```

then the error is present in all mentioned versions of GCC.

**According to the latter example, does it mean that I can not use a pointer without explicitly specifying second argument even though pointed function does not need it?**

**According to the main example does it mean that GCC 5.3.1 incorrectly implements this behavior in connection with template wrapper?**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dereferencing a function with default arguments - C++14 vs C++11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47013385/dereferencing-a-function-with-default-arguments-c14-vs-c11)

Comment: _"As far as I am concerned if I use a pointer to a function"_ Did you miss a 'then X should happen'?

Answer (score 1):

It's fine to use a function with default arguments using any of its possible signatures, but you've introduced an inconsistency yourself. You've specifically defined `Foo` as wrapping a pointer to a two-argument function, so you'd better call it with two arguments. If you want to call it with one argument, use it as a pointer to a one-argument function.

I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish with integral_constant.

Comment: std::integral_constant was used to store a pointer to function in it's value member.

Comment: No, I get that. I'm just not sure why you're unhappy with just using a function pointer. Ordinarily, `integral_constant` is used for certain compile-time dispatching tricks (like on the length of a tuple) which don't really apply to function pointers.